# Exclude _id attribute from mongodb result including the subdocuments in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The database has a lot of nesting. I can exclude _id for one layer but how to do that for the whole of the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `$project` for this type of scenarios.

For Example, consider the document:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  title: "abc123",
  isbn: "0001122223334",
  author: { last: "zzz", first: "aaa" },
  copies: 5
}
```

The following query will exclude the _id from the document

```
db.books.aggregate( [ { $project : { _id: 0, title : 1 , author : 1 } } ] )
```

You can refer the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)